# Best way to implement HUD. - Cocos2D

Tags: design-patterns, cocos2d-iphone, layer, scene

Hello my fellow coders.

I was developing a game, but I came across a small problem.

What could be the best way to implement a HUD? 
Im talking design here, not the actual way of creating one.

For example.

You've got :

GamePlayScene

-Inside the Scene you've got:

-BackgroundLayer

-GamePlayLayer

So, where would you add the HUD?
What do you think would be more manageable?
Would you do an extra layer or just add it on gameplay?

If I chose to add an extra Layer, what could be the best way to communicate between layers?

Background does the game "map"(If you would like to see it as FF series).

Gameplay does the sprites(enemies,user,projectiles,collectables)

Thanks for your time!

Hope you have a great time

Comment: extra layer, communicate through scene, ie scene has gameLayer etc property

Answer (score 0):

I'd let the scene instantiate the layers as LearnCocos2D says. And I'd pass a HUD reference to all objects that want to use it. If a projectile wants to use HUD, pass a HUD reference to it at init!